Неверно работает функция
Получается, когда загоняешь в процесс 2 аккаунта или более, для первого аккаунта все нормально, а для второго аккаунта подцепляется все с первого. То есть весь прайс кеш и тд, и функция крашится из-за того, что нет тех предметов, которые он пытается выставить. (на втором, третьем и других аккаунтах в потоке выдается
"Не удалось найти ордеры для следующих предметов: AVIATOR CRATE, Toxic - S1897")
В чем заключается проблема - не понимаю. ГПТ не помогает
Суть всей функции:
Получаем предметы с БД аккаунта, получаем инвентарь определенной игры на аккаунте, проверяем, есть ли предмет из инвентаря в базе данных, если да то рассчитываем: получаем цену всех 10 лотов. Проверяем, если расхождение между 1 лотом и остальными условно меньше 3-4% (ну как в ситуации с ясенем) то мы можем взять цену первого лота, отнять копейку и выставить свой, перед этим проверим, что то, сколько мы получим не меньше или равно закупочной цены
Если разницы уже больше 3-4% то рассчитываем среднее арифметическое первых 10 лотов (либо 9, если первый лот со слишком большой разницей отошел от средней арифметической), после проверяем, что то, сколько мы получим не меньше или равно закупочной цене
P.s. использую aiosteampy
async def market_sell(self, login: str, game_name: str, min_deviation: float = 1.0, max_deviation: float = 5.0) -> None:
    price_cache = {} #for cache prices
    items_not_in_database = []
    error_count = 0

    sync = {query[0]: int(query[2]) for query in Database(base_adress_generator(login)).execute("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE game = ?", (game_name, )).fetchall()}

    async with SteamClientManager(login) as client:
        if await client.is_session_alive() is True:
            try:
                inventory, count, _ = await client.get_inventory(AppContext[game_name])
                ser = {item.asset_id: serialize_inventory_item(item) for item in inventory}

                result_json = {
                    "inventory": ser,
                    "total_count": count
                }

                with open(f"{Constants.INFO_FOLDER}\\inventories\\{game_name}_{login}.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                    json.dump(result_json, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
            except Exception as e:
                return

            data = result_json
            items = data.get("inventory", {})
            if not items or len(items) == 0:
                return

            for item_id, item in items.items():
                id = int(item_id)
                name = item.get("market_hash_name", "Unknown item")

                if name in sync:
                    buy_price = int(sync[name])

                    if name in price_cache:
                        price = price_cache[name]
                    else:
                        price = None

                    if not price:
                        try:
                            name_id = await client.get_item_name_id(obj = name, app = App[game_name])
                            histogram, ltmd = await client.get_item_orders_histogram(name_id)
                            market_prices = [order.price / 100 for order in histogram.sell_order_graph[:10]]
                            first_lot_price = market_prices[0]
                        except Exception as e:
                            error_count += 1
                            if error_count >= 10:
                                return

                            await asyncio.sleep(6)
                            continue

                        try:
                            average_price_10 = sum(market_prices) / len(market_prices)
                            deviation = abs(first_lot_price - average_price_10) / average_price_10 * 100
                            deviation = round(deviation, 2)

                            if deviation <= max_deviation:
                                price = first_lot_price - 1
                            else:
                                average_price_9 = sum(market_prices[1:]) / 9
                                deviation_9_10 = abs(average_price_10 - average_price_9) / average_price_10 * 100
                                deviation_9_10 = round(deviation_9_10, 2)

                                if deviation_9_10 > 5:  # 5%
                                    price = average_price_9
                                else:
                                    price = average_price_10
                        except Exception as e:
                            error_count += 1
                            if error_count >= 10:
                                return

                            continue

                        price = int(price * 100)
                        price_cache[name] = int(price)

                    sell_price = price_cache[name]
                    to_receive = buyer_pays_to_receive(sell_price)[2]

                    if to_receive > buy_price and to_receive > 0:
                        if isSelling(login, name):
                           
                            if game_name == "PUBG":
                                count_pubg = 0
                                if count_pubg > 20:
                                    break
                                else:
                                    count_pubg += 1
                                   
                            try:
                                    #await client.place_sell_listing(
                                    #    obj = id, #id предмета
                                    #    app_context = AppContext[game_name],
                                    #    price = sell_price
                                    #)
                                make_log("debug", f"Market.market_sell[{login}]", f"Продажа предмета {name} | продажа: {price / 100} руб. (к получению: {to_receive / 100} руб.), закупочная: {buy_price / 100} руб.")
                                    #await asyncio.sleep(6)
                            except Exception as e:
                                error_count += 1
                                if error_count >= 10:
                                    return

                                await asyncio.sleep(6)
                                continue
                        else:
                            make_log("debug", f"Market.market_sell[{login}]", f"У предмета {name} отключена продажа")
                    else:
                        make_log("warning", "market", f"Какая то хуйня с ценой. {price} ({to_receive})")
                else:
                    if name not in items_not_in_database:
                        items_not_in_database.append(name)
                        continue

        if items_not_in_database:
            make_log("warning", f"Market.market_sell[{login}]", f"Не удалось найти ордеры для следующих предметов: {', '.join(items_not_in_database)}")


Для начала разделите функцию на отдельные независимые блоки, вынесите их в отдельные функции. Разбирать проблемы в простыне кода на несколько экранов - занятие неблагодарное. Небольшие функции легко понимать и тестировать. А сейчас ни тесты написать, ни понять, что происходит толком нельзя. Начните с рефакторинга в общем.

@CrazyElf попробуйте предоставить вариант решения. Я не понимаю, что конкретно тут стоит разбить на отдельные функции, если все используется только для одной

Ну вот это всё "получаем", "проверяем", "рассчитываем" можно было бы вынести в отдельные функции. Я это за вас не буду делать, у меня работа есть. Но я вам могу подсказать, как сделать ваш код лучше для понимания вами же.
